SHAP plots with RNN/LSTM
I want to use the beeswarm and dependence plot from the shap package which requires an Explanation object as the shap_values argument. When doing it for XGBoost like this
explainer = shap.TreeExplainer(model)
shap_obj = explainer(X_train)
shap_values = explainer.shap_values(X_train)

this works perfectly fine, however, for my RNN and LSTM when I do this
n_traing_samples = 2
explainer = shap.DeepExplainer(model, X_train)
shap_obj = explainer(X_train[:n_traing_samples])

I get the error that 'DeepExplainer' object has no attribute 'masker'. It seems like this is a common problem and I guess it has something to do with the fact that my data is like (number of training samples, sequence length, number of features). Therefore, I tried to reshape my data into this format (number of training samples * sequence length, number of features), which did not work either, i.e. like this
explainer = shap.DeepExplainer(model, X_train)
shap_obj = explainer(X_train[:n_traing_samples].reshape(n_traing_samples*sequence length, number of features))

I can use the summary plot like this
shap.summary_plot(shap_values[:, :, :, 0].reshape(n_traing_samples*24, 49), X_train[:2].reshape(n_traing_samples*24, 49), plot_type='bar', feature_names=FEATURES, plot_size=(10, 5))

since it does not require an Explanation object.
Does anyone know if I can fix the issue somehow?
Thanks
